# Build failed error: cannot find symbol if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)

Tags: java, android, cordova

I tried building my ionic app after development; but in the process the following errors surfaced:

> C:\incidentApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\moust\cordova\videoplayer\VideoPlayer.java:123:
> error: cannot find symbol if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=
> Build.VERSION_CODES.R) { ^ > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> symbol:   variable R location: class VERSION_CODES
> C:\incidentApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\moust\cordova\videoplayer\VideoPlayer.java:124:
> error: cannot find symbol
> dialog.getWindow().getInsetsController().hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
> ^ symbol:   variable Type location: class WindowInsets
> C:\incidentApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\moust\cordova\videoplayer\VideoPlayer.java:124:
> error:  cannot find symbol
> dialog.getWindow().getInsetsController().hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
> ^ symbol:   method getInsetsController() location: class Window Note:
> Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile
> with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files use
> unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked
> for details. 3 errors
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED 24 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 23 up-to-date
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2m 5s c:\incidentApp\platforms\android\gradlew:
> Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
> C:\incidentApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\moust\cordova\videoplayer\VideoPlayer.java:123:
> error:  cannot find symbol if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=
> Build.VERSION_CODES.R) { ^ symbol:   variable R location: class
> VERSION_CODES
> C:\incidentApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\moust\cordova\videoplayer\VideoPlayer.java:124:
> error:  cannot find symbol
> dialog.getWindow().getInsetsController().hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
> ^ symbol:   variable Type location: class WindowInsets
> C:\incidentApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\moust\cordova\videoplayer\VideoPlayer.java:124:
> error:  cannot find symbol
> dialog.getWindow().getInsetsController().hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
> ^ symbol:   method getInsetsController() location: class Window Note:
> Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile
> with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files use
> unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked
> for details. 3 errors
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I'd tried everything(removing of android package and re-installing) I could lay my hands on but still not working.

Below is my **build.gradle**

```
 project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="29.0.3" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=22 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 5.1
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=29 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
```

Answer (score 39):

Simply upgrade the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 31 in your android/app/build.gradle file.

Comment: i have upgraded but not working

Comment: Update your sdk version to 33. Some plugin you added uses android 13(api 33) check, but couldn't find in your code 
see support [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75158364/error-cannot-find-symbol-if-build-version-sdk-int-build-version-codes-tirami)

Answer (score 28):

Updated-: make sure you set `compileSdkVersion` in your android/app/build.gradle file to `31`

Old-: I encounter this error while using the Geolocator plugin in the flutter app. to Solve this error you have to open LocationMapper.java (you can find this path in your Debug console). and remove this part

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
```

and also make sure your android compile version is 30 (For GeoLocator Build.gradle)

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
      position.put("is_mocked", location.isMock());
   }
```

Comment: You sir , you are a lifesaver! I spent hours to get geolocater to work and finally i fixed it thanks to you! Thank you so much!

Comment: The correct way is to pin the geolocator's version number. Refer [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/867#issuecomment-942430988)

Answer (score 24):

`Build.VERSION_CODES.R` only exists in [API 30](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES#R), but you're compiling with API 29.

The compileSdkVersion should be set to 30 if you want to use `Build.VERSION_CODES.R`.

###### Update for cordova-android@10

As of cordova-android@10, `compileSdkVersion` has been removed `android-targetSdkVersion` is unified to set both the target & compile SDK versions, so that they always remain consistent.

###### Update for cordova-android@11

As of cordova-android@11, the ability to independently set the compile SDK and target SDK separately has returned.

Just like before, use `android-targetSdkVersion` preference to set the Target SDK. Use `android-compileSdkVersion` preference to set the Compile SDK.

Like before, the target SDK will default to a particular version that cordova-android has been tested with. Cordova-android@11 uses API 32 by default. The compile SDK will default to the configured Target SDK.

Generally speaking, the target and compile should match, but with cordova-android@11 (and 9), you can set the compile SDK higher while keeping the target SDK lower, which can be useful for things that requires the API codes for compatibility checks.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Find and change this line form 30 to 31.

Answer (score 7):

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33 // increase one by one 
        }
    }
```

In our case, it was 31 when the error was occurring, we increase it to compileSdkVersion 33, and the error is solved. You can increase it by 1 each time until your error is not solved.

Comment: updating to 33 solve the problem for me ! , 31 didn't work

Answer (score 3):

I just changed from compileSdkVersion 30 to compileSdkVersion 31 in build.gradel and everything became okay

Answer (score 2):

If you like me, use notifee, look at this:

> https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/release-notes
>
> 6.0.0 [Android] BREAKING CHANGE: Added support for requesting permission on Android 13 via requestPermission, the minimum
> compileSdkVersion required has increased to 33. And, to support this
> feature, the targetSdkVersion must also be increased to 33.

Answer (score 0):

****work for me****

***in android/build.gradle***

compileSdkVersion = 32  // <---- increase one by one

Answer (score 0):

I’m using **npm i react-native-background-actions** then I got this error

and my react native version is `"react-native": "0.62.2",`
so is just to update the(android/build.gradle) `compileSdkVersion 30 to 31`

```
subprojects {
afterEvaluate {project ->
    if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 31    
            buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just update your sdk version to 33. Because some plugin you added uses android 13 (api 33) check, but couldn't find in your code.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 33 // Just increase your sdk version
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Check which SDK version you downloaded and make all same that:-
compileSdkVersion XX
minSdkVersion XX
targetSdkVersion XX**