# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' when building mobile app with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to build an app using Cordova (with *cordova build android*), unfortunately I ran into this error "Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'".
I am providing all needed information that I can think of.

- Cordova version: **11.0.0**
- Cordova Installed platforms:
  android **9.1.0**,
  ios **5.1.1**
- Java version: **1.8.0_341**
- Npm version: **6.14.15**
- Node version: **14.18.1**
- JAVA_HOME path: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_341.jdk/Contents/Home`
- Android SDK Platforms: **from API level 29 up to 32**
- Android SDK Tools: **from API level 29 up to 32**

Working machine : MacBook Pro with M1 cpu, macOS: Ventura 13.1

My config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget
        android-packageName="com.test.testapp"
        ios-CFBundleIdentifier="com.test.testapp"
        version="1.0.0"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>Test App</name>
    <description>
        Just a Test App.
    </description>
    <author email="test@test.com" href="http://test.com">
        Test Team
    </author>
    <content src="sourcePath"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait"/>
    <platform name="android">
        <icon src="../assets/android/icon.png"/>
        <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="31"/>
        <preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />
        <config-file parent="/manifest/application" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
                android:value="true" />
        </config-file>
        <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application/activity" mode="merge">
            <activity android:exported="true"/>
        </edit-config>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine"/>
        </feature>
        <allow-navigation href="*://js.stripe.com/*"/>
        <allow-navigation href="*://stripe.com/*"/>
        <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
        <edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
            <string>Needs for locating user's order delivery address</string>
        </edit-config>
        <edit-config target="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
            <string>Needs for locating user's order delivery address</string>
        </edit-config>
        <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine"/>
        <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
        <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="000000"/>
        <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true"/>
    </platform>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
    <engine name="android" spec="<9.0.0"/>
    <engine name="ios" spec="~5.1.1"/>
</widget>
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "displayName": "HelloCordova",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ecosystem:cordova"
  ],
  "author": "Apache Cordova Team",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "cordova-android": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "^2.7.3",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "xml-js": "^1.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

My generate_builds.sh file:

```
### Constants

# Must be equal to <widget> -> <name> in app/config.xml file
APP_NAME="Test App"

### Operations

# navigate to app/ directory
cd app/

# delete all generated folders
rm -rf platforms/ node_modules/

# run npm install to make sure that new libraries are installed
npm install

# this command will add all plugins listend in package.json file in /plugins folder and also generate ios and android platforms
cordova prepare

# Add Plugman plugins - we use Plugman to install some plugins only for android platform and some only for iOS platform. In this way we avoid plugin conflicts.
# IMPORTANT: Plugins installed with Plugman are not listed in the package.json neither in config.xml files

# for ios platform
plugman install --platform ios --project ./platforms/ios/ --plugin cordova-plugin-firebasex --plugins_dir ./plugins/
plugman install --platform ios --project ./platforms/ios/ --plugin cordova-plugin-stripe --plugins_dir ./plugins/
plugman install --platform ios --project ./platforms/ios/ --plugin cordova-plugin-dynamic-applepay-stripe --plugins_dir ./plugins/

# for android platform
plugman install --platform android --project ./platforms/android/ --plugin cordova-plugin-firebasex --plugins_dir ./plugins/
plugman install --platform android --project ./platforms/android/ --cordova-plugin-androidx --plugins_dir ./plugins/
plugman install --platform android --project ./platforms/android/ --cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release --plugins_dir ./plugins/
plugman install --platform android --project ./platforms/android/ --plugin cordova-plugin-apple-pay-google-pay --plugins_dir ./plugins/
# Replace all iOS image folder with the one from /app/assets/ios/Images.xcassets

# delete generated folders
rm -rf platforms/ios/"$APP_NAME"/Images.xcassets/
cp -r ../assets/ios/Images.xcassets/ platforms/ios/"$APP_NAME"/Images.xcassets/


# Add firebase push notification files in ios and android platforms


# ios

rm -f platforms/ios/"$APP_NAME"/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist
cp  ../assets/ios/firebase/GoogleService-Info.plist platforms/ios/"$APP_NAME"/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist

# android

rm -f platforms/android/app/google-services.json
cp  ../assets/android/firebase/google-services.json platforms/android/app/google-services.json


# Replace Google Pay plugin files in android platform.

rm -f platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/plugin/googlepay/ApplePayGooglePay.java
cp  ../assets/android/gpay/ApplePayGooglePay.java platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/plugin/googlepay/ApplePayGooglePay.java
```

More details about the error:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/Users/userName/Documents/Projects/TestApp/app/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/firebase/FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:261: error: cannot find symbol
            if(getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable S
  location: class VERSION_CODES
/Users/userName/Documents/Projects/TestApp/app/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/firebase/FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:261: error: cannot find symbol
            if(getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                                                                                                                             ^
  symbol:   variable S
  location: class VERSION_CODES
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/userName/Documents/Projects/TestApp/app/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/firebase/FirebasePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I have tried many possible solutions found here in StackOverflow, so far nothing helped for my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly comes from FirebasePluginMessagingService. But I don't see where it is added. So I guess it is added by plugman, since you log `Plugins installed with Plugman are not listed in the package.json neither in config.xml files`
Can you try to remove that plugin and see if your project builds.
The error arises, because S doesn't exist in you older targetSDK (S is 31 I believe) source: [Build failed error: cannot find symbol if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044161/build-failed-error-cannot-find-symbol-if-build-version-sdk-int-build-versio). So see if you can use an older version of the plugin or a higher version of targetSDK. For this you probably also have to increment cordova-android.

I think it is important to get a working project as a starting point, which is why I would remove the plugin first. Then upgrade the required versions and only then add back the plugin.
I updated cordova android from 9 to 11 in several steps and also the targetSDK from 29 to 31 in 2 steps. In each steps at least one thing broke, so trying to do several of these at once is pretty much undoable. Some things that broke were:

- Jdk needs to be upgraded from 8 to at least 11 (I think this was required by targetSDK 30)
- WhiteList plugin and every reference to it needs to be removed (also in plugins, by patching them) (required by cordova 10+)
- Node needs to be at least 14
- this spec: `<engine name="android" spec="<9.0.0"/>` seems to conflict with the actual cordova-android version you're using.
  I am not exactly sure which updates require what. But the cordova update docs should tell you, they exist for every version: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2021/07/20/cordova-android-10.0.0.html
  targetSDK versions themselves also have several requirements. So be sure to check those as well.

Comment: Thank you @Mister_CK, I will try your suggestions !