# error: cannot find symbol if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)

Tags: android, react-native, build, react-native-notifications

react-native build failed after installing `@notifee/react-native`

```
Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
/Users/apple/repos/GPSTracker/node_modules/@notifee/react-native/android/src/main/java/io/invertase/notifee/NotifeeApiModule.java:241: error: cannot find symbol
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable TIRAMISU
  location: class VERSION_CODES
/Users/apple/repos/GPSTracker/node_modules/@notifee/react-native/android/src/main/java/io/invertase/notifee/NotifeeApiModule.java:268: error: cannot find symbol
        new String[] {Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS},
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable POST_NOTIFICATIONS
  location: class permission
Note: /Users/apple/repos/GPSTracker/node_modules/@notifee/react-native/android/src/main/java/io/invertase/notifee/NotifeeReactUtils.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
```

Comment: What's your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: compileSdkVersion  31  targetSdkVersion  31 both

Comment: Update your sdk version to 33. Some plugin you added uses android 13(api 33) check, but couldn't find in your code.

Comment: yes. Aftab updating to 33 it solved. thanks @Nitish